# Creating a subnet using REST API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to provision  a subnet using the below REST call

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data @subnet-data.json https://<userid>:<apikey>@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Network/4601/createSubnet
```

where 4601 is the id of my Network.

The JSON Payload is:

```
{
"parameters": [
    {
        "networkIdentifier": "172.31.10.0",
        "cidr": 24,
        "podName": "dal09.pod01",
    }
]
```

}

But I get the following error

```
{"error":"Bad request","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_WebService_BadRequest"}
```

Please let me know the correct way to order a Subnet.
Also if you can let me know how to find the correct/required parameters that would be great.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look this forum please:

- [SoftLayer API: Ordering Subnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126098/softlayer-api-ordering-subnet)

If you have any question or doubt, let me know

---

> **Updated**

The price id depends from the catalog, try this request please, you will be able to see the id for **Global IPv4**:

```
http://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/0/getItemPrices?objectFilter={"itemPrices":{"item":{"description":{"operation":"Global IPv4"}}}}

Method: Get
```

If you don't have success, try the request below, sometimes it's necessary to encoded because we are using an objectFilter:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/0/getItemPrices?objectFilter=%7B%22itemPrices%22%3A%7B%22item%22%3A%7B%22description%22%3A%7B%22operation%22%3A%22Global+IPv4%22%7D%7D%7D%7D

Method: Get
```

Replace: **$user** and **$apiKey** with you own information

Comment: I saw the code given by you in the link above
But when I use the json provided there :
`{  "parameters": [  {
      "packageId": 0,
      "prices": [
        {
          "id": 19065
        }
      ],
      "quantity": 1,
      "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Subnet"}]}`

I get the error `{"error":"Price # 19065 does not exist.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}`

So I tried to find the correct price. But I cannot see when i use '/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/0/getItemPrices' then I cannot see any price related to subnet, such as 'global ipv4'

Comment: Please, review the **Updated** section in my answer, if you have any doubt or issue, let me know

Comment: Hello, 
I got the following responses:

`curl https://$user:$apikey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/0/getItemPrices?objectFilter=%7B%22itemPrices%22%3A%7B%22item%22%3A%7B%22description%22%3A%7B%22operation%22%3A%22Global+IPv4%22%7D%7D%7D%7D

output:

[]
`

and

`curl -g https://$user:$apikey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/0/getItemPrices?objectFilter={"itemPrices":{"item":{"description":{"operation":"Global IPv4"}}}}

output:

curl: (52) Empty reply from server
`