# softlayer api: How to order Public Secondary IP Addresses when I ordering?

Tags: api, ip-address, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, subnet

I want to order Public Secondary IP Addresses when I ordering. And How to submit these order infomation by softlayer api ?

[image]

Comment: This is a good starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126098/softlayer-api-ordering-subnet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To submit the order information described above, you need to fill the parameter **"itemCategoryQuestionAnswers"** during the order, that parameter can be found in datatypes like [Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest) and [Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Hardware_Server)

Below is an example in JSON for REST:

```
"itemCategoryQuestionAnswers":[
            {
                "answer": "2",
                "categoryId": 14,
                "questionId": 14
            },
            {
                "answer": "4",
                "categoryId": 14,
                "questionId": 15
            }
        ]
```

The example above belongs to the first two questions in the form. As you can see, it is necessary to know the id of **categoryId** and **questionId** parameters. Follow the steps below.

**CategoryID**

As [greyhoundforty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2032632/greyhoundforty) comment you, the link [SoftLayer API: Ordering Subnet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126098/softlayer-api-ordering-subnet) 
is a good starting point. On that page [mcruz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5094381/mcruz) shows how to execute the method [Product_Item_Category::getSubnetCategories](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Item_Category/getSubnetCategories). The method returns some thing like this:

```
    {
        "categoryCode": "global_ipv6",
        "id": 331,
        "name": "Global IPv6",
        "quantityLimit": 0
    },
    {
        "categoryCode": "sec_ip_addresses",
        "id": 14,
        "name": "Public Secondary IP Addresses",
        "quantityLimit": 0
    },
```

On this case the **categoryId is 14** for category **"Public Secondary IP Addresses"**.

**QuestionID**

To get all questions related to the category **"sec_ip_addresses"** you can use the method [Product_Item_Category::getQuestions](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Item_Category/getQuestions) or [Product_Item_Category::getQuestionReferences](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Item_Category/getQuestionReferences). On this case I'll show you how execute **getQuestionReferences** method:

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Item_Category/14/getQuestionReferences?objectMask=[question]

Method: GET
```

It should returns something like this:

```
{
    "id": 61,
    "questionId": 14,
    "required": true,
    "question": {
        "description": "The number of IP addresses expected to be used within the next 30 days.",
        "id": 14
    }
},
{
    "id": 62,
    "questionId": 15,
    "required": true,
    "question": {
        "description": "The number of IP addresses expected to be used within the next 12 months.",
        "id": 15
    }
},
```

Now you can know the **questionId** of each question in the form.

**Order Virtual Guest with a Secondary Public Ip Address**

Below is an example in REST to order a virtual guest with a secondary ip address and two first questions in the form.

**Note:** Don't forget change **[username]**, **[apikey]**, **prices**, and other ids with your own data

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder    
Method: POST

Body JSON:
{
    "parameters":[
        {
            "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest",
            "packageId": 46,
            "location": "AMSTERDAM",
            "quantity": 1,
            "prices":[
                {"id":14640},
                {"id":11644},
                {"id":9205},
                {"id":22272},
                {"id":52231},
                {"id":21},
                {"id":2202},
                {"id":13945},
                {"id":55},
                {"id":57},
                {"id":58},
                {"id":420},
                {"id":418},
                {"id":22}
            ],
            "virtualGuests":[
                {
                    "hostname": "test",
                    "domain": "example.com"                 
                }
            ],
            "itemCategoryQuestionAnswers":[
                {
                    "answer": "2",
                    "categoryId": 14,
                    "questionId": 14
                },
                {
                    "answer": "4",
                    "categoryId": 14,
                    "questionId": 15
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}
```

## **About your REST structure**

I don't know what REST client you are using, but I was able to reproduce your issue in a RESTclient from firefox, in other REST clients like [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/) I'm just getting errors.

Basically, you are getting empty response because your JSON structure have some mistakes. First, all data in body needs to be into **"parameters"** object, please review the example above. Second, value of **"sshKeyIds"** needs to be into double quotes because it is an string. Finally, I recommend you **put all objects and string values into double quotation mark due to it is the JSON standard format**, you can verify this information in [jQuery.parseJSON single quote vs double quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355655/jquery-parsejson-single-quote-vs-double-quote) and http://www.json.org/.

**Important:** Before to use placeOrder method I recommend you to **execute verifyOrder first**. When, you are ready to order just change verifyOrder by placeOrder in the URL request.

I modified your request as following

```
https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder
Method: POST

Body in JSON format:

{
    "parameters":[
        {
            "complexType" : "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest",
            "location" : "449604",
            "packageId" : 46,
            "quantity" : 1,         
            "useHourlyPricing" : true,
            "virtualGuests" : [
                {
                    "domain" : "aaa.com",
                    "hostname" : "sshkey_07"
                }
            ],
            "sshKeys" : [
                { "sshKeyIds" : ["620913L"]   }
            ],
            "prices" : [
                {"id" : 1644 },
                {"id" : 2202 }, 
                {"id" : 2259 }, 
                {"id" : 273  }, 
                {"id" : 1640 }, 
                {"id" : 17442}, 
                {"id" : 905  }, 
                {"id" : 21   }, 
                {"id" : 57   }, 
                {"id" : 55   }, 
                {"id" : 58   }, 
                {"id" : 420  }, 
                {"id" : 418  }, 
                {"id" : 22   }, 
                {"id" : 1800 }
            ],
            "itemCategoryQuestionAnswers" : [{
                    "answer" : "4",
                    "questionId" : 14,
                    "categoryCode" : "sec_ip_addresses",
                    "categoryId" : 14
                }, {
                    "answer" : "4",
                    "questionId" : 15,
                    "categoryCode" : "sec_ip_addresses",
                    "categoryId" : 14
                }, {
                    "answer" : "aaaa",
                    "questionId" : 16,
                    "categoryCode" : "sec_ip_addresses",
                    "categoryId" : 14
                }, {
                    "answer" : "allesa",
                    "questionId" : 9,
                    "categoryCode" : "sec_ip_addresses",
                    "categoryId" : 14
                }, {
                    "answer" : "product manager",
                    "questionId" : 10,
                    "categoryCode" : "sec_ip_addresses",
                    "categoryId" : 14
                }, {
                    "answer" : "xxx@mail.com",
                    "questionId" : 11,
                    "categoryCode" : "sec_ip_addresses",
                    "categoryId" : 14
                }, {
                    "answer" : "xxxxxxxxx",
                    "questionId" : 12,
                    "categoryCode" : "sec_ip_addresses",
                    "categoryId" : 14
                }, {
                    "answer" : "1",
                    "questionId" : 13,
                    "categoryCode" : "sec_ip_addresses",
                    "categoryId" : 14
                }
            ]           
        }
    ]
}
```

Let me know if you have any doubt or need further assistance.

Comment: I set the parameters like this, but the order result that itemCategoryQuestionAnswers is empty returned by placeOrder.

Comment: I can order successfully, but returned to the order information of 'itemCategoryQuestionAnswers' is also []. Thank you for your reply, regards~

Comment: Sorry for late response, I tested this behavior since yesterday and I always get the same result, all questions/answers are saved when virtual server is created from web page but for some reason they are not saved when using the API  (SOAP or REST). I reported this issue in order to be fixed. I will update this post when it is fixed.